# angular http request for a big API call hungs at the stage "CAUTION: request is not finished yet" and it hungs the browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, google-chrome, http

I am requesting an API, which returns the diff of files. Content of this data is sometime huge (Around 900KB of data).
When I request this API separately in chrome browser, it works fine and returns data within seconds:
https://example.com/1234/file.diff

But when the same API I call using Angular http method, it hungs at  "CAUTION: request is not finished yet" State (Seen from network tab of chrome). and browser becomes unresponsive.

```
myService.getFileDiff("https://example.com/1234/file.diff").
 then(function (response) {
  $scope.fileDiff = response;
  }, function(error){
   console.log("Some error occured." +error);
});
```

[image]

Can anyone please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Hey, did you resolve this. I am facing a similar issue in my site.